# Concurrent access to variables despite concurrentbag usage

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing

Following is the code snippet in my production environment for a method in which i have used parallel.foreach and concurrent bag

```
Parallel.ForEach(lstTasks, options, item =>
                {
                    Repository.AssignmentDTO.TaskAssignmentDTO tskVar;
                    while (lstConcurrentObj.TryTake(out tskVar))
                    {
                         finaltaskslist.Add(ProcessTaskAssgn(item, tskVar));    
                    }

                    //}
                });
```

finaltaskslist is a list where i add objects after performing a few long operations in the method ProcessTaskAssgn....

lstConcurrentObj above is the concurrent bag into which i have added a few initialized objects all with the same values.

This list is then used to populate a datatable.

However when i look at the entries in the datatable , it is clear that entries have been repeated or mixed ,
 inferring that my ProcessTaskAssgn method wasnt really threadsafe and concurrent operations had given incorrect results.
Is my usage of concurrentbag correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is causing your problem is that multiple threads are taking the same information simultaneously

lstConcurrentObj is already filled, right? ConcurrentBag is intended for a Producer-Consumer scenario, where you have one or more threads reading and another thread(s) writing data to the collection. In your case, you're just reading (consuming) the collection in a parallel way. You can just read it parallelly (through Parallel.ForEach, for example) and populate you database normally.